# Wordpress, how to simplify selecting from a large list of taxonomies

Tags: jquery, wordpress, autocomplete, admin, taxonomy

When editing a post on the wordpress admin I need to be able to, with relative ease, find and select a taxonomy from a list of maybe 300 - 500 taxonomies. The taxonomies will be assigned a parent taxonomy, which will total about 20 overall. I'm looking for either an autocomplete type deal or having an accordion that expands when the parents are clicked. Can it be done / is there an existing plugin?

Comment: "list of maybe 300 - 500 taxonomies" prob not a good idea....anyway have a google for wordpress admin jquery. I don't think anyone would write a plugin for this so its up to yourself to do this. This is a coding website really, where you can ask for help if you run into difficulty in learning a language or applying it,  if you're not up to learning php, js, jquery hire a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes it can be done, and there are existing plugins. I was able to find one and have linked to it below

https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-taxonomy-autocomplete/screenshots/

If the plugin listed above does not meet your needs, one will have to be created (it is possible). As David commented, you will either have to learn to code or hire someone to build it for you.

Comment: Ah that looks exactly perfect, thanks. I am a developer, it's just that this particular task is for a tender offer, meaning they would be against me putting in the extra time needed to develop a custom solution.